# Accessing JSON values in C++

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to write a program that navigates your local disc in Unreal Engine for a small application. I have put together a REST server using Gradle, and long story short, I am given a JSON with a machines directories. I want to pull out the specific directories names, to be returned as string (FText specifically, but that not too important here) array.

I found a library created by nLohmann on github (https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which seems to be the best way to handle a JSON in c++. For the life of me, however, I can't figure out how to pull the directory names out. I've tried an iterator and a straightforward .value() call.

The code and a JSON example are below, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
char buffer[1024];

FILE *lsofFile_p = _popen("py C:\\Users\\jinx5\\CWorkspace\\sysCalls\\PullRoots.py", "r");
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), lsofFile_p);
_pclose(lsofFile_p);

std::string rootsJson(buffer);
string s = rootsJson.substr(1);
s = ReplaceAll(s, "'", "");

//here my string s will contain: [{"description":"Local Disk","name":"C:\\"},{"description":"Local Disk","name":"D:\\"},{"description":"CD Drive","name":"E:\\"}]


//These are two syntax examples I found un nlohmann's docs, neither seems to work 
auto j = json::parse(s);
string descr = j.value("description", "err");
```

Comment: Another C++ JSON option (that *I* quite like) is [PicoJSON](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) (https://github.com/kazuho/picojson/blob/master/README.mkdn).

Comment: Probably way too heavy for you, but I also use Qt's C++ Json implementation.  It works really well.

Comment: "neither seems to work" is not a useful problem description. "Hello, Bob's auto repair? My car doesn't seem to work, can it be fixed?"

Comment: Notice you have an array of dicts. So, it's not correct to do j.value directly to get the value of one of the dict members. First you have to determine which array element (which dict) you want to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem comes from number of `\` in your literal string. You need 5 `\` for `C:\\` : `C:\\\\\`.

Here is a working example :

```
#include "json.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main(){

    json j = json::parse("[{\"description\":\"Local Disk\",\"name\":\"C:\\\\\"},{\"description\":\"Local Disk\",\"name\":\"D:\\\\\"},{\"description\":\"CD Drive\",\"name\":\"E:\\\\\"}]");

    cout << j.is_array() << endl;

    for (auto& element : j) {
      std::cout << "description : " << element["description"] << " | " << " name : "  << element["name"] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```